# Is it possible to force google url shortner to generate YOUTU.BE urls instead of GOO.GL

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

I looking for a Google shortener API to generate short url for youtube videos with **youtu.be** url.
Is it possible to force Google url shortner API to generate YOUTU.BE urls instead of GOO.GL?

[image: youtube url shortener]

Below is what I can generate now using [google API](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/urlshortener/v1/urlshortener.url.insert?_h=3&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522longUrl%2522%253A%20%2522https%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fwatch%253Fv%253Dpih6gTJNu7s%2522%250A%257D&)
Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxx
{
 "longUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pih6gTJNu7s"
}
```

Response

```
{

 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/ruPUvs",
 "longUrl": "http://google.com/"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible to shorten a youtube link into a youtu.be using googles url shortener. Think about it as all the url shortened links are under the website goo.gl/ 
goo.gl is just the name of the website.